# File read and write with string

Tags: android, android-activity

I have got the error: "java.io.FileNotFoundException," for the standard input and output of files. The purpose is to write a string to a file and later read it. The file seems to be written but not open for read. Is there any reason for the file not being open? In the following the second part, reading file, is the problem. Thanks in advance for any advice.

```
public void test(View view){
    //writing part
    String filename="file.txt";
    String string="Hello world!";

    FileOutputStream outputStream;
    try {
        outputStream=openFileOutput(filename,MODE_PRIVATE);
        outputStream.write(string.getBytes());
        outputStream.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }  

    //read part
    FileInputStream inputStream;
    int length = (int) filename.length();
    byte[] bytes=new byte[length];
    try {
        inputStream=new FileInputStream(filename);
        inputStream.read(bytes);
        inputStream.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    String data = new String(bytes);
}
```

Comment: If you use openFileOutput to write to a file then use openFileInput to read from it.

Comment: 'int length = (int) filename.length();'. The number of characters of the file name ? Has nothing to do with the file size. That cannot work.

Comment: It's wrong thanks.  "length" has been replaced with 512. I found that the code works if FileInputStream(filename) is replaced with openFileInput(filename). The input output pair seems to be symmetric: openFileOutput-openFileInput. The trouble is that the read value is 512 bytes while the original string is the simple, "Hello, world!."

Comment: Normally you would not know the size of the file and you would read from the input stream in a loop in a buffer. And then add the buffers together. Use  int nread =  inputStream.read(bytes); to see how many bytes are actually read.

Answer (score 0):

Hi please try below methods for read and write operation on file . hope it will help you

**Method for read file as string**

```
p_filePath = "your full file path";

public static String readFileAsString(String p_filePath) throws IOException, Throwable
    {
        String m_text;
        BufferedReader m_br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(p_filePath));
        try
        {
            StringBuilder m_sb = new StringBuilder();
            String m_line = m_br.readLine();
            while (m_line != null)
            {
                m_sb.append(m_line);
                m_sb.append(File.separator);
                m_line = m_br.readLine();
            }
            m_text = m_sb.toString();
        }
        finally
        {
            m_br.close();
        }
        return m_text;
    }
```

**Method for write string to file**

```
    public static void writeStringToFile(String p_string, String p_fileName) throws CustomException
    {
        FileOutputStream m_stream = null;
        try
        {
            m_stream = new FileOutputStream(p_fileName);
            m_stream.write(p_string.getBytes());
            m_stream.flush();
        }
        catch (Throwable m_th)
        {

        }
        finally
        {
            if (m_stream != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    m_stream.close();
                }
                catch (Throwable m_e)
                {

                }
                m_stream = null;
            }
        }
    }
```

Add below permission in your manifest also

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Comment: OP is writing to internal memory and hence does not need that permission. Because he is writing to internal memory he uses a relative path. No need to use full paths.

Answer (score 0):

You should write in external storage then make sure that file is created or not.

Comment: Why should OP write to external memory?